# How can I delete 1 row from a table using a submit button?

Tags: php, sql, foreach, delete-row

I am using a foreach loop to display my data. Im getting data from a table with reservations, which the customer is able to delete.

This is my current code:

```
if(isset($_POST['verwijder']))
{
$resid= $pers->reserveringnummer;

$query = "DELETE FROM reservering WHERE reserveringnummer = :resid;";
$stm = $con->prepare($query);
$stm->bindParam(':resid', $resid, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
if($stm->execute() == true)
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = 'greservering.php';
    </script>
    <?php
}   else {
echo ("Mislukt");
}
}

//pers->reserveringnummer = reservation id loaded from database
```

This code selects the id of the row the button is in, and deletes the row with this id. It all worked with 1 row, but when I tried it with 2 rows, it deleted both.

All of this happens inside of a foreach loop, so every row has a submit button with the same name (verwijder).

When I click a submit button, all of the buttons execute the action, and delete themselves.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

EDIT:

Form code: (just a button per row)

```
//query to get all reservations
foreach ($result as $pers) {
?>
    //some row data
    <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="dropdown-item text-danger" name="verwijder" value="Verwijder">
    </form>
<?php
//delete code using submit
}
```

Comment: can you add the form to the question please?

Comment: I added the form, but its just 1 button

Comment: you have `$resid` and `$kamid` ~ the query seems confused as the parameter used is `:resid` yet you try to use `$kamid` as the value!??!
The form will only submit a field called `verwijder` with a value of `verwijder` - this seems utterly pointless and it does nothing. For the form to perform any meaningful tasks it needs to know what record it is supposed to update - here it does not

Comment: Wow, my mistake, I changed this, yet it stills deletes every record.

Comment: There is insufficient code above to know what is really happening. What is `$pers` - where is that defined? Presumably the data is displayed in a table - where is that?

Comment: Added some extra code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't passing any information on which reservation should be deleted. 
How does `$pers->reserveringnummer;` load the number and know which of the buttons was pressed?

In the delete form where you display the reservations you would probably need to pass the number in a hidden input field like this

`<input type="hidden" name="resid" value="<?= $resid ?>" />`

and then in your delete code you use this id to delete the reservation.

Answer (score 0):

As the code you have added to the question is incomplete and hard to follow perhaps a little semi-pseudo code might help. The form that you are using for each record must have a way to identify the particular record that is to be deleted. One typical way would be to use a `hidden` field that holds the ID of that particular record. When the form is submitted the ID will be available in the POST array data and then can be used to build the SQL query. The below code is  a guess at how you may have constructed your HTML display and how it is build ~ using the pseudo `while( $rs=$results->fetch() )` etc - it should give an idea though how to proceed perhaps.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['resid'] ) ){

        $resid = $_POST['resid'];
        $query = "DELETE FROM reservering WHERE reserveringnummer = :resid;";
        $stm = $con->prepare( $query );
        $result = $stm->execute( array( ':resid' => $resid ) );
    }

?>

<table>
<?php
    while( $rs=$results->fetch() ){

        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>Name:{$rs->name}</td>
            <!-- other table cells -->
            <td>
                <form method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='resid' value='{$rs->reserveringnummer}' />
                    <input type='submit' />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>";

    }
?>
</table>
```